# Bernoulli percolation

Tags: probability-theory

Given a random Bernoulli matrix with probability given, how do I check there exists a path starting from the centre point outwards?

Comment: A typical approach for problems like this is to try to reduce the problem to something smaller and then solve the smaller problem. For example how about peeling off the outermost layer to create a (n - 2) by (n - 2) array. How can you define the outermost layer of the new problem? Keep peeling off layers. How can you tell you have finished? What is the final result when you get to the middle? For bonus points, can you tell at some point the problem is unsolvable and quit early? Good luck and have fun.

Answer (score 1):

Let n be the row and column dimension of the matrix m and use the code in the question to generate it.  We use 3 here so we can show the results compactly.  From this we will produce a graph whose node numbers are 1, 2, ..., n^2 which we show using the matrix function next.  We then iterate `colleage` in mazeGen over the nodes to generate an adjacency list L, convert that to an undirected igraph g, plot it (graph is at very end) and show the distances between every pair of nodes.

In the plot the center cell (5) in the matrix is represented by a white circle, the zero cells are red and the remaining 1 cells are green.

In the distance matrix the distance is measured along edges of the graph, not by steps in the matrix itself and the edges of the graph only connected vertical or horizontal adjacent cells which are both 1.

We also show near the end the set of nodes that are reachable from 5 but it could also be derived from the distance matrix by looking at row (or column) 5.

```
library(igraph)
library(mazeGen)

set.seed(123)
n <- 3
m <- rndm_matrix(n, 0.8)
center <- (1+n^2)/2
m[center] <- 1  # force to be 1
m
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    1    0    1
## [2,]    1    1    0
## [3,]    1    1    1
attr(,"p")
[1] 0.8

im <- matrix(1:n^2, n, n) # correspondence between matrix entries and node nos
im
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    1    4    7
## [2,]    2    5    8
## [3,]    3    6    9

L <- lapply(seq_along(m), function(i) if (m[i] == 1) mazeGen:::colleage(i, n))
nodes <- seq_along(m)[m == 1]
L <- lapply(L, intersect, nodes)
g <- graph_from_adj_list(L)
g <- as.undirected(g)
```

We now show the distances between nodes.

```
distances(g)
##       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
##  [1,]    0    1    2  Inf    2    3  Inf  Inf    4
##  [2,]    1    0    1  Inf    1    2  Inf  Inf    3
##  [3,]    2    1    0  Inf    2    1  Inf  Inf    2
##  [4,]  Inf  Inf  Inf    0  Inf  Inf  Inf  Inf  Inf
##  [5,]    2    1    2  Inf    0    1  Inf  Inf    2
##  [6,]    3    2    1  Inf    1    0  Inf  Inf    1
##  [7,]  Inf  Inf  Inf  Inf  Inf  Inf    0  Inf  Inf
##  [8,]  Inf  Inf  Inf  Inf  Inf  Inf  Inf    0  Inf
##  [9,]    4    3    2  Inf    2    1  Inf  Inf    0
```

This is all nodes reachable from the center node including itself:

```
center_comp <- subcomponent(g, center)
center_comp
## [1] 5 2 6 1 3 9

# boundary nodes
boundary <- c(im)[row(m) %in% c(1, n) | col(m) %in% c(1, n)]

# boundary nodes in center's component
intersect(center_comp, boundary)
## [1] 2 6 1 3 9


V(g)$color <- ifelse(m == 1, "green", "red")
V(g)$color[center] <- "white"
plot(g)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: node 5 is the middle node.  In this case *all* of the other nodes are edges (so the problem is a bit trivial), but any edge node with a finite distance to the center node can be reached.

Comment: Have updated the answer with a better example, more description, colored nodes in the plot (node 5=white, nodes whose matrix cell is 0=red, nodes whose matrix cell is 1=green).  Note that node 7 is a 1 in the matrix but is not reachable from node 5.  Also we added the `subcomponent` command to directly show which nodes are reachable  from 5 so you don't even have to figure it out from the `distances` output.

Comment: Michael, the nodes of the graph are the cells of the matrix (9 nodes in the case of a 3x3 matrix) and the edges connect adjacent cells that are 1.  Other cells are not connected by edges so the distance is finite and non-zero if and only if there is a path between those two nodes.